# ctrl keys not working properly

Tags: keyboard

Ubuntu 19.10 (laptop)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys aren't working(not registered) or not always

- tried on my USB stick with Ubuntu 19.10 live and keys worked so I assume the keboard is not faulty
- restart and resetting key shortcuts didn't help
- checked mappings of keys all good there
- used `xev` to see if the keys are registered at least and I got something rather odd:

  pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys and nothing showed up in `xev` at first after few more tries keys start to work `xev` shows the key presses since the start and afterwards keys work as intended for a few moments
- so I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys only after I press one of them a couple of times

Is there a way to find what is going one and fix this bug?

Comment: Did this happen previously? Can you relate it to anything you did? Does it happen if you create and try with a new user?

Comment: It did not happened previously
i cannot relate it to anything I am working on since and before the problem appeared.
the problem persists if i add a new user just tested it

Comment: I recently had a very similar issue in 16.04. Under "onboard preferences" -> "input options" I found I needed to reset my "input event source" to "GTK" instead of "xinput". Then my ctrl keys worked.